# Java LWJGL new Rendering issue windows

Tags: java, windows, opengl, lwjgl

I have been working on a simple LWJGL practice project for a bit and just recently stumbled into a new issue. Now with every project i due i save working backups in multiple places. I was running a Windows 8.1 OS and recently upgraded to Windows 10 and suddenly all of my backups and current program have the rendering error as seen below. I've tried to run my program on a windows 8.1 OS and it works fine there.

Is there some new windows driver update that could be causing this rendering issue?

Or is there some incompatibility with windows 10 and LWJGL i havn't been able to find out about?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
before you render any objects into your world, make sure you are using the inbuilt depth testing, this can be done by using this line of code:

GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

This should work for you, as it is forgotten in most cases that this happens!

-Kore

EDIT:
Also dont forget to clear the buffer aswell!!
GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: i have those lines in my code. It's not that my program doesn't work, it does, but not on my computer when running windows 10. It works on my PC with windows 8.1 and other computers running windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh the LWJGL files (remove as an ext. jar then re add it)?

Comment: yes i've updated java and tried the version being ran on the computers with windows 10 that worked.

Comment: if you dont feel safe about publicly showing your code, we could also work out other means of that if you want, but im 99% sure that people here wont steal your code :) we just want to help